# Only return 2 items from listview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a listview, lvSelectRequestItems that contains three columns. 'Box, 'Custref' and 'description'. At the moment the code I am using returns all items in all 3 columns. However, what I would like to do is just return box and description. Can someone show me how to adjust my code to achieve that. Thank you.

```
        For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.lvSelectRequestItems.SelectedItems
            item.Remove()
            Me.lvSelectedItems.Items.Add(item)
        Next
```

Comment: @Max could you show by code please as I am fairly new to vb.net. Thanks

Comment: lvselected item is two cloumns

Comment: @pankeel that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this way:

try this:

1 ,3 is your colums index

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.lvSelectRequestItems.SelectedItems
            item.Remove()
        Dim li As New ListViewItem
        li.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text
        li.SubItems.Add(item.SubItems(3).Text)
        Me.lvSelectedItems.Items.Add(li)
        Next
```

Comment: after further usage it seems that your amended code stops one of my variables from working. In my original code it worked fine, but now is not catching the value. I am attaching code and would appreciate your thoughts. Private Sub lvSelectedItems_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvSelectedItems.SelectedIndexChanged

        msg = CStr(lvSelectedItems.Items.Count)

        'MessageBox.Show(msg)

    End Sub Thanks